# sprite animation using cocos2d working on simulator but not on device

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone

i've got a 2 frame sprite animation running along a bezier path using ccbezierto. this works perfectly fine on the simulator, no warning no errors. but strange thing is on my iphone 3GS device, the animation and the ccbezierto action does not show up on screen, the sprite disappears for the duration of the supposed animation and pops back at the designated position.

so anyone got experience with this kind of thing? or is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Check the case on the spelling of your sprite sheet -- the simulator will check for up and downcase versions of the same resource, the iPhone won't.